# How to delete all except for some specific folder under parent-folder

Tags: command-line, delete

So here's content under my `/html` folder.

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-121 html]# ls
a             wp-activate.php       wp-content         wp-mail.php
b             wp-admin              wp-cron.php        wp-settings.php
healthy.html  wp-blog-header.php    wp-includes        wp-signup.php
index.php     wp-comments-post.php  wp-links-opml.php  wp-trackback.php
license.txt   wp-config.php         wp-load.php        xmlrpc.php
readme.html   wp-config-sample.php  wp-login.php
```

I want to delete everything except for folder `a` and `b` without having to move `a`/`b` folder to another folder.
What's the command to do that?

Comment: Will the exceptions always be a single letter?

Comment: That's the name of my folder. I named them a and b. Just for testing! Not always single letter, maybe hyphen or sth else.

Comment: I get that but I asked if the answer should rely on the fact that they are a single letter or not?  If not, what would the criteria be to exclude them?

Comment: Keep in mind that computer do not ***yet*** have mind reading technology and you need to tell the computer exactly what you want done.  In your simple example, I would use `rm ??*` which would ignore single letter names.

Comment: Ah, i see that :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `find` with a negation (at your own risk).

find all file and folders named "a" or "b":

```
find -name a -o -name b
```

find all files and folders name "a" or "b" in the current directory"

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name a -o -name b
```

find all files and folders not named "a" and not named "b" in current directory:

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -name a ! -name b
```

also exclude current directory from result

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -name a ! -name b ! -name .
```

now you can use `rm` to delete all founded elements:

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -name a ! -name b ! -name . -exec rm -rv {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this command to delete all (including hidden) except selected files/folders in the CURRENT directory.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "file1.php" ! -name "file2.js" ! -name "dir1" ! -name "dir2" ! -name . -exec rm -r {} \;
```